# Any resources on how to create extensions with kickstarter in typo3 4.5?

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.5

I have to create an extension, that allows to create database records from the backend and as well display them(extra frontend plugin?). I can extend a existing plugin with the new pi* directory and files. But i can't for the life of me get a new extension to work, namly I set it up in kickstarter, generate it as a frontend plugin for example and it is not being displayed nor in the extensions tab or in the general plugins tab, when adding a plugin to a page. All the needed files are there and the structure of them is correct as well. I checked it several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly question: Have you installed the extension? When you create an extension with kickstarter it is not automatically installed.

Comment: I did not and that is it probably. I can't think of any other reason. Could you possibly give me some hints on how to install the generated extension? Do I hook it up somwhere or do I have to register it?

Comment: Found it, thank you so much. I was sitting on it since friday ripping my hair off... I own you a fat beer

Answer (score 0):

In which year do you live?
TYPO3 4.5 is way too old.
Please update the TYPO3 Installation.

Comment: This project we're running won't be updated. It will be rewritten tho, so I'm hoping for better times :(